# Hydrogen atom Radial wave function integrations

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

I wanted to do some integrations with the radial wave function for Hydrogen atom. The radial wave function is given by,
$$R_{nl}(r)=2^{l+1} e^{-\frac{r}{a n}} \sqrt{\frac{(-l+n-1)!}{a^3 n^4 (l+n)!}} \left(\frac{r}{a
   n}\right)^l L_{-l+n-1}^{2 l+1}\left(\frac{2 r}{a n}\right),$$
where $L^-_-(-)$ is the associated Laguerre polynomial. Now the radial integration comes with an weight $r^2dr$. I wanted to do the following integrations,
$$\int_0^\infty r^{-2}R_{n'l'}(r)R_{nl}(r)r^2dr$$
$$\int_0^\infty r^{-3}R_{n'l'}(r)R_{nl}(r)r^2dr$$
Is it possible to derive general formula for the above integrations involving $n,n',l,l'$? Are these results known?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I don't understand